# requests post function result is forbidden

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently trying to **scrape** the result from https://omia.org/search/ by inputting values into `Trait id (OMIA id):` input box using BeautifulSoup.
Since I am trying to get a response from a page, I know that I have to use the requests.post(). However, if I use response = requests.post("https://omia.org/search/",params = {"omia_id":179}), I get 403 status code along with message saying I need to do something with CSRF cookie.

What do I need to do to get the correct response using .post()?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a CSRF error, it is likely that you need to include the CSRF header and cookie. For this case, you will need the `csrftoken` cookie and a matching `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in the request body.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.get("https://omia.org/search/")
    cookies = '; '.join([x+"="+y for x,y in res.cookies.items()])

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    csrfmiddleware = soup.select_one('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]')['value']

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3835.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cookie': cookies
    }

    data = f'csrfmiddlewaretoken={csrfmiddleware}&search_type=simple&query=test&query_type=or&result_type=phene'

    response = s.post('https://omia.org/results/', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
    print(response)
```

`<Response [200]>`

Comment: I can see whats kinda going on. But additionally, if I want to include my input to certain input box (for this case `179 into <input id="id_omia_id" name="omia_id" size="30" type"text">` tag) do I include it in data variable? if so how do I need to format that?

Comment: @Young Please make another question if you're asking about how to send a POST request through javascript using html form variables.